# How do you prevent electromagnetic radiation emitting from a new house?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, telescopes

Does anyone know how to prevent electromagnetic radiation emitting from a new house?  We live very near a radio telescope and we're told that electromagnetic radiation from domestic houses causes detrimental radio interference on the telescope. Does anyone know what sort of building materials can be used to prevent this in a new build house and why?

Comment: *"Does anyone know what sort of building materials can be used to prevent this in a new build house and why?"* conductive materials or cladding (e.g steel sheet), because [faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage)

Comment: You might try inquiring with the operators of the facility.  It's surely something they deal with (or have dealt with).  Something simple like chicken wire behind the sheet-rock (or paneling, etc) might be enough to help a lot.

Comment: If this is a genuine problem, there will already be some local regulations in place which new builds will have to follow. On the other hand, it might simply be scare tactics from the local NIMBY group.

Comment: This appears to be more of an engineering question than a physics question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not prepared to stop using a wi-fi network, mobile phone communications or LCD televisions then you are going to have to do some fairly serious engineering.

In principle you can construct a type of Faraday cage by enclosing your house, or at least the rooms in which you wish to confine any signals, with a conductive mesh and then earth that mesh. The mesh size needs to be significantly smaller (at least a factor of a few) than the shortest wavelengths that the observatory is interested in.

Of course you won't be able to receive radio signals and mobile phone signals inside your house if you do that, so you might also want to set up external aerials to relay those inside the house.

Comment: Or relay them out??

Comment: Actually, they should have a very low gain or a sidelobe canceller  or beamforming to have a very low gain horizontally (towards you and the other houses). If you are the only house around it should be easier. And if you use one antenna to get out of your house they should get a tap and use it to feed a canceller.

Comment: @BobBee Relaying signals out would defeat the point of not emitting signals, wouldn't it? You could try not living near a radio telescope.

Comment: Well, some people do and still want to talk to the outside. Anyway, this Q has been closed so no sympathy for those who live near a telescope, sounds like that's the mantra.